# scope of stopEvent

Tags: javascript

how can i call stopEvent within init?

```
testObj.prototype =
{
    init: function(wrapper)
    {       
        wrapper.onclick = function(e){
            stopEvent(e);  //getting error stopEvent not defined
        };
    },
    stopEvent: function(e){
        if(e.preventDefault)
            e.preventDefault();
        else
            e.returnValue = false
    }
}
```

Comment: setting `element.onclick` directly to a function will not provide any parameters when called in IE- so `e` will be undefined. you can add the line `e = e || window.event;` or use `addEventListener/attachEvent`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could *capture this*:

```
init: function(wrapper) {       
    var _this = this;
    wrapper.onclick = function(e) {
        _this.stopEvent(e);
    };
}
```